# javamail attach "noname" from inside Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jakarta-mail, apache-tomee

I'm trying to send an email using javamail inside a web application using TomEE. My problem is that when I attach a file such as a PDF, the file that I recive is named "noname". Also I don't recieve the body text.

As an observation, if I execute my code from a "main" program (in an other project), the email is sent perfectly. Here is the code:

```
public class EnviaCorreo{


static Properties mailServerProperties;
static Session getMailSession;
static MimeMessage generateMailMessage;


public void generateAndSendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

    System.out.println("\n 1st ===> setup Mail Server Properties..");
    mailServerProperties = System.getProperties();
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    System.out.println("Mail Server Properties have been setup successfully..");

    System.out.println("\n\n 2nd ===> get Mail Session..");
    getMailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailServerProperties, null);
    generateMailMessage = new MimeMessage(getMailSession);
    generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("xxx@gmail.com"));
    generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress("yyy@gmail.com"));
    generateMailMessage.setSubject("Foo store has bought strawberries");

    MimeMultipart multiParte = new MimeMultipart();
    BodyPart adjunto = new MimeBodyPart();
    adjunto.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource("/home/foo/Desktop/FooProject/src/main/resources/fruit/6781430324446945.pdf")));
    adjunto.setFileName("readme.pdf");

    BodyPart texto = new MimeBodyPart();
    texto.setText("Success!!");



    multiParte.addBodyPart(texto);
    multiParte.addBodyPart(adjunto);

    generateMailMessage.setContent(multiParte, "text/html");
    System.out.println("Mail Session has been created successfully..");


    System.out.println("\n\n 3rd ===> Get Session and Send mail");
    Transport transport = getMailSession.getTransport("smtp");


    transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "yyy@gmail.com", "foopsswd123()");
    transport.sendMessage(generateMailMessage, generateMailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
}
```

#### Bonus

I'm working with TomEE and iText for PDF generation. Where should I put the folder where I save dynamically generated PDFs to?

Comment: Are you using the same version of JavaMail in both cases?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show when running in TomEE?  If you [change Session.getDefaultInstance to Session.getInstance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), does it help?

Answer (score 1):

TomEE uses geronimo javamail (in tomee lib) by default. You can replace it by the version you used in your main and add geronimo-locator and geronimo-registry 
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-osgi-locator/1.1/geronimo-osgi-locator-1.1.jar
and http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-osgi-registry/1.1/geronimo-osgi-registry-1.1.jar as well in libs

If you dont want to change the version maybe use tomee.xml session to get your session injected. I know for gmail you have to provide an authenticator for instance with geronimo javamail